# OpenMP omp_get_max_threads() return value

Tags: openmp

Does `omp_get_max_threads()` return the value of `$OMP_NUM_THREADS` when `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable is defined?

It look like so on my system (Linux/gcc). Even if OMP_NUM_THREADS is set to a ridiculously high value...

Calling it in the beginning of `main`, i.e., not inside any (nested) parallel region (if it makes a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that `omp_get_max_threads()` returns the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. And you can set this as high as you want: a thread is a software construct and has nothing to do with the number of cores you have. For that, use `omp_get_num_procs()`. Normally it wouldn't make much sense to have more threads than cores, but it could: if the work in the threads is very different, or threads can pause because of locks and such, you could get a higher processor utilization by having more threads than cores.